# React Props Cards component duplicate table

Tags: html-table, components, react-props, card

i have a problem. I'm with a project just for test, using React Props/Cards component, and my table is duplicate your rows TH for each row JSON coming database. Thats my project.

how do I solve this problem, for the table to pass only the lines of the TD part and not repeat TH for each line

```
`import './App.css'

import { Card } from './components/card/card';
import { useSistemasData } from './hooks/useSistemasData';

function App() {
const {data} = useSistemasData();

return (
\   <div className="container"\>
\    <h1\>Sist\</h1\>
\    <div className="card-grid"\>
     {data?.map((sistemasData) =\> (
\    <Card
    name_client={sistemasData.name_client}
name_respons={sistemasData.name_respons}
data_regis={sistemasData.data_regis}
tittle_regis={sistemasData.tittle_regist}
text_regis={sistemasData.text_regis}
/\>
))}
\</div\>
\</div\>

)
}

export default App
```

```
import moment from "moment"

interface CardProps {
    name_client: string,
    name_respons: string,
    data_regis: Date,
    tittle_regis: string,
    text_regis: string,
    image_regis: string
}
export function Card({nome_cliente, nome_responsavel, data_registro, titulo_registro, texto_registro, imagem_regis} : CardProps){
 return(
 <div className="card">
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
       <th>Clien</th>
       <th>Respons</th>
       <th>Regis</th>
       <th>Tittle</th>
       <th>Descr</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>{name_client}</td>
    <td>{name_respons}</td>
     <td>{moment(data_regis).format('DD/MM/YYYY kk:mm:ss')}</td>
     <td>{tittle_regis}</td>
     <td><textarea id="idtext" readOnly cols={100} rows={5} value={text_regist}></textarea></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
    )
}``
```

i need the table not to duplicate the top part

```
`<tr>
  <th>Clien</th>
  <th>Respons</th>
  <th>Regis</th>
  <th>Tittle</th>
  <th>Descr</th>
 </tr>`
```